# If force on neutral particle in electric field is zero then how come a comb can attract a neutral piece of paper?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

If force on neutral particle in electric field is zero then how come a comb can attract a neutral piece of paper?

Answer (score 1):

When you put a little piece of paper (dielectric) into en electric field the dielectric will be polarized so that a macroscopic electric dipole will be created. This induced  electric dipole experiences an attractive force in the inhomogeneous electric field of the comb. Thus the paper pieces are attracted to the electrically charged comb.